# What is the fastest way to transpose the bits in an 8x8 block on bits?

Tags: c, embedded, transpose, bitarray, dspic

I'm not sure the exact term for what I'm trying to do. I have an `8x8` block of `bits` stored in `8 bytes`, each byte stores one row. When I'm finished, I'd like each byte to store one column.

For example, when I'm finished:

```
Byte0out = Byte0inBit0 + Bit0inByte1 + Bit0inByte2 + Bit0inByte3 + ...
Byte1out = Bit1inByte0 + Bit1inByte1 + Bit1inByte2 + Bit1inByte3 + ...
```

What is the *easiest* way to do this in **C** which performs well? This will run on a dsPIC microcontroller

Comment: So, the answer should be *fastest* or *easiest*?

Comment: I assume you want Byte0Out= Byte0inBit0 + Byte1inBit0*2 + ...

Comment: The term that you are looking for is "transpose".

Comment: migrate to http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Casey: It's not a codegolf, it is a real usable question.

Comment: by `Byte0inBit0` I assume you mean `Bit0inByte0`

Comment: [Possible duplicate of Bitwise transpose of 8 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243985/bitwise-transpose-of-8-bytes); this was not originally noticed as the title text incorrectly said rotate, when the content was about transposing.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This code is cribbed directly from ["Hacker's Delight" - Figure 7-2 Transposing an 8x8-bit matrix](http://books.google.com/books?id=iBNKMspIlqEC&lpg=SL20-PA11&vq=Transposing%20an%208x8-bit%20matrix&pg=SL20-PA11#v=snippet&q=Transposing%20an%208x8-bit%20matrix&f=false), I take no credit for it:

```
void transpose8(unsigned char A[8], int m, int n, 
                unsigned char B[8]) {
   unsigned x, y, t; 

   // Load the array and pack it into x and y. 

   x = (A[0]<<24)   | (A[m]<<16)   | (A[2*m]<<8) | A[3*m]; 
   y = (A[4*m]<<24) | (A[5*m]<<16) | (A[6*m]<<8) | A[7*m]; 

   t = (x ^ (x >> 7)) & 0x00AA00AA;  x = x ^ t ^ (t << 7); 
   t = (y ^ (y >> 7)) & 0x00AA00AA;  y = y ^ t ^ (t << 7); 

   t = (x ^ (x >>14)) & 0x0000CCCC;  x = x ^ t ^ (t <<14); 
   t = (y ^ (y >>14)) & 0x0000CCCC;  y = y ^ t ^ (t <<14); 

   t = (x & 0xF0F0F0F0) | ((y >> 4) & 0x0F0F0F0F); 
   y = ((x << 4) & 0xF0F0F0F0) | (y & 0x0F0F0F0F); 
   x = t; 

   B[0]=x>>24;    B[n]=x>>16;    B[2*n]=x>>8;  B[3*n]=x; 
   B[4*n]=y>>24;  B[5*n]=y>>16;  B[6*n]=y>>8;  B[7*n]=y; 
}
```

I didn't check if this rotates in the direction you need, if not you might need to adjust the code.

Also, keep in mind datatypes & sizes - `int` & `unsigned (int)` might not be 32 bits on your platform.

BTW, I suspect the book (Hacker's Delight) is essential for the kind of work you're doing... check it out, lots of great stuff in there.

Comment: +1 for the first answer I've seen that's relevant to OP's question (embedded). Lisp, x86 asm, and naive slow-as-hell implementations are all rather useless for embedded...

Comment: what does `m` and `n` stands for?

Comment: @est `m` and `n` are used to specify the block of bytes to transpose when `A` and `B` are larger matrices.  If you only have an array of 8 bytes `m` and `n` are both `1`, so you might just remove them and simplify a little.

Comment: Does anybody know about how to "upgrade" the algorithm to a bigger matrix, I'm interested in 12x12-bit or 16x16-bit matrix transposition.

Answer (score 5):

**If you are looking for the simplest solution:**

```
/* not tested, not even compiled */

char bytes_in[8];
char bytes_out[8];

/* please fill bytes_in[] here with some pixel-crap */

memset(bytes_out, 0, 8);
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        bytes_out[i] = (bytes_out[i] << 1) | ((bytes_in[j] >> (7 - i)) & 0x01);
    }
}
```

**If your are looking for the fastest solution:**

[How to transpose a bit matrix in the assembly by utilizing SSE2.](http://mischasan.wordpress.com/2011/07/24/what-is-sse-good-for-transposing-a-bit-matrix/)

Comment: I don't think your code does the transposition. Maybe you need to write < instead of <<?

Comment: Considering the post was tagged "embedded" and "C", and something like 99% of processors on the planet are NOT x86 Pentium4+ CPUs, your SSE2 x86 assembly-language solution isn't the most useful.  But considering how many responders here mentioned SIMD, x86 ASM or whatever, maybe I'll just go crawl back into my hole...

Comment: @whoplist: Thanks, code fixed by replacing < with << (your comment was opposite btw, I think that was just typo)

Comment: Thanks, whoplist. Actually, you were seeing my struggle as a wordpress noob accidentally creating emoticons :-)  For example, I now know that you can't post C code like "if (len < 8)" ... a space btw 8 and ) is required.

Comment: @Mischa Indeed the SSE2 `pmovmskb` instruction is very suitable (efficient) for these type of bit matrix manipulations, if the cpu supports SSE2. See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51988761/2439725), which uses the AVX2 `vpmovmskb` instruction to rotate an 8x8 bit matrix.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds a lot like a so-called "Chunky to planar" routine used on displays that use bitplanes. The following link uses MC68K assembler for its code, but provides a nice overview of the problem (assuming I understood the question correctly):

http://membres.multimania.fr/amycoders/sources/c2ptut.html

Answer (score 2):

Lisp prototype:

```
(declaim (optimize (speed 3) (safety 0)))
(defun bit-transpose (a)
  (declare (type (simple-array unsigned-byte 1) a))
  (let ((b (make-array 8 :element-type '(unsigned-byte 8))))
    (dotimes (j 8)
      (dotimes (i 8)
    (setf (ldb (byte 1 i) (aref b j))
          (ldb (byte 1 j) (aref a i)))))
    b))
```

This is how you can run the code:

```
#+nil
(bit-transpose (make-array 8 :element-type 'unsigned-byte
               :initial-contents '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)))
;; => #(85 102 120 128 0 0 0 0)
```

Occasionally I disassemble code to check that there are no unnecessary calls to safety functions.

```
#+nil
(disassemble #'bit-transpose)
```

This is a benchmark. Run the function often enough to process a (binary) HDTV image.

```
#+nil
(time 
 (let ((a (make-array 8 :element-type 'unsigned-byte
              :initial-contents '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)))
       (b (make-array 8 :element-type 'unsigned-byte
              :initial-contents '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))))
   (dotimes (i (* (/ 1920 8) (/ 1080 8)))
     (bit-transpose a))))
```

That took only took 51ms. Note that I'm consing quite a lot because the function allocates new 8 byte arrays all the time. I'm sure an implementation in C can be tweaked a lot more.

```
Evaluation took:
  0.051 seconds of real time
  0.052004 seconds of total run time (0.052004 user, 0.000000 system)
  101.96% CPU
  122,179,503 processor cycles
  1,048,576 bytes consed
```

Here are some more test cases:

```
#+nil
(loop for j below 12 collect
  (let ((l (loop for i below 8 collect (random 255))))
    (list l (bit-transpose (make-array 8 :element-type 'unsigned-byte
                :initial-contents l)))))
;; => (((111 97 195 202 47 124 113 164) #(87 29 177 57 96 243 111 140))
;;     ((180 192 70 173 167 41 30 127) #(184 212 221 232 193 185 134 27))
;;     ((244 86 149 57 191 65 129 178) #(124 146 23 24 159 153 35 213))
;;     ((227 244 139 35 38 65 214 64) #(45 93 82 4 66 27 227 71))
;;     ((207 62 236 89 50 64 157 120) #(73 19 71 207 218 150 173 69))
;;     ((89 211 149 140 233 72 193 192) #(87 2 12 57 7 16 243 222))
;;     ((97 144 19 13 135 198 238 33) #(157 116 120 72 6 193 97 114))
;;     ((145 119 3 85 41 202 79 134) #(95 230 202 112 11 18 106 161))
;;     ((42 153 67 166 175 190 114 21) #(150 125 184 51 226 121 68 58))
;;     ((58 232 38 210 137 254 19 112) #(80 109 36 51 233 167 170 58))
;;     ((27 245 1 197 208 221 21 101) #(239 1 234 33 115 130 186 58))
;;     ((66 204 110 232 46 67 37 34) #(96 181 86 30 0 220 47 10)))
```

Now I really want to see how my code compares to Andrejs Cainikovs' C solution
(**Edit: I think its wrong**):

```
#include <string.h>

unsigned char bytes_in[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
unsigned char bytes_out[8];

/* please fill bytes_in[] here with some pixel-crap */
void bit_transpose(){
  memset(bytes_out, 0, 8);
  int i,j;
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) 
      bytes_out[i] = (bytes_out[i] << 1) | ((bytes_in[j] >> (7 - i)) & 0x01);
}

int
main()
{
  int j,i;
  for(j=0;j<100;j++)
    for(i=0;i<(1920/8*1080/8);i++)
      bit_transpose();
  return 0;
}
```

And benchmarking it:

```
wg@hp:~/0803/so$ gcc -O3 trans.c
wg@hp:~/0803/so$ time ./a.out 

real    0m0.249s
user    0m0.232s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Each loop over the HDTV image takes 2.5ms. That is quite a lot faster than my unoptimized Lisp.

Unfortunately the C code doesn't give the same results like my lisp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main()
{
  int j,i;
  bit_transpose();
  for(i=0;i<8;i++)
    printf("%d ",(int)bytes_out[i]);
  return 0;
}
wg@hp:~/0803/so$ ./a.out 
0 0 0 0 1 30 102 170
```

Comment: +1 for your huge efforts and a lisp. Always wanted to learn that language but never went past emacs customization :)

Comment: Thank you. Some recreational Lisp is always nice as a break from real work. Right now I have to synchronize hardware, which I inconveniently couldn't design for synchronization. Fortunately I can use Lisp in my main job as well :-)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! I've updated my code - can you please update also your answer with following: bytes_out[i] = (bytes_out[i] << 1) | ((bytes_in[j] >> (7 - i)) & 0x01);

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the [get column in a bitboard problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14537831/995714) and can be solved efficiently by considering those input bytes as 8 bytes of a 64-bit integer. If bit 0 is the least significant one and byte 0 is the first byte in the array then I assume you want to do the following

```
                              Column 7 becomes...
                              ↓
[ b07 b06 b05 b04 b03 b02 b01 b00   [ b70 b60 b50 b40 b30 b20 b10 b00 ← row 0
  b17 b16 b15 b14 b13 b12 b11 b10     b71 b61 b51 b41 b31 b21 b11 b01
  b27 b26 b25 b24 b23 b22 b21 b20     b72 b62 b52 b42 b32 b22 b12 b02
  b37 b36 b35 b34 b33 b32 b31 b30  →  b73 b63 b53 b43 b33 b23 b13 b03
  b47 b46 b45 b44 b43 b42 b41 b40  →  b74 b64 b54 b44 b34 b24 b14 b04
  b57 b56 b55 b54 b53 b52 b51 b50     b75 b65 b55 b45 b35 b25 b15 b05
  b67 b66 b65 b64 b63 b62 b61 b60     b76 b66 b56 b46 b36 b26 b16 b06
  b77 b76 b75 b74 b73 b72 b71 b70 ]   b77 b67 b57 b47 b37 b27 b17 b07 ]
```

with bXY is byte X's bit number Y. In that form rotating the left-most column is just packing all the most significant bits into a single byte in reverse order, and similarly other columns can be rotated

To do that we mask out all the last 7 columns and read the array as an `uint64_t`. The result is

```
0b h0000000 g0000000 f0000000 e0000000 d0000000 c0000000 b0000000 a0000000
   ↑        ↑        ↑        ↑        ↑        ↑        ↑        ↑
   b77      b67      b57      b47      b37      b27      b17      b07
```

in little endian, with `abcdefgh` are b07 to b77 respectively. Now we just need to multiply that value with the [magic number 0x0002040810204081](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51750902/995714) to make a value with `hgfedcba` in the MSB which is what we expected

```
uint8_t transpose_column(uint64_t matrix, unsigned col)
{
    const uint64_t column_mask = 0x8080808080808080ull;
    const uint64_t magic       = 0x0002040810204081ull;
    
    return ((matrix << col) & column_mask) * magic >> 56;
}

uint64_t block8x8;
memcpy(&block8x8, bytes_in, sizeof(block8x8));
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
block8x8 = swap_bytes(block8x8);
#endif

for (unsigned i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    byte_out[i] = transpose_column(block8x8, 7 - i);
```

Because you treat the 8-byte array as `uint64_t`, you may need to align the array properly to get better performance because that way only a single memory load is needed

---

In AVX2 Intel introduced the [PDEP](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html) instruction (accessible via the `_pext_u64` intrinsic) in the [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2) instruction set for this purpose so the function can be done in a single instruction

```
data[i] = _pext_u64(matrix, column_mask << (7 - col));
```

But unfortunately this won't work in dsPIC as you expected

More ways to transpose the array can be found in the [chess programming wiki](https://web.archive.org/web/20170810054329/https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Flipping+Mirroring+and+Rotating)

Answer (score 1):

You really want to do something like this with SIMD instructions with something like the GCC vector vector support: http://ds9a.nl/gcc-simd/example.html

Comment: That would be nice, but this needs to run on a dsPIC microcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted an optimized solution you would use the SSE extensions in x86.

You'd need to use 4 of these SIMD opcodes.

- MOVQ - move 8 bytes
- PSLLW - packed shift left logical words
- PMOVMSKB - packed move mask byte

And 2 regular x86 opcodes

- LEA - load effective address
- MOV - move

```
byte[] m = byte[8]; //input
byte[] o = byte[8]; //output
LEA ecx, [o]
// ecx = the address of the output array/matrix
MOVQ xmm0, [m]
// xmm0 = 0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|m[7]|m[6]|m[5]|m[4]|m[3]|m[2]|m[1]|m[0]
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
// eax = m[7][7]...m[0][7] the high bit of each byte
MOV [ecx+7], al
// o[7] is now the last column
PSLLW xmm0, 1
// shift 1 bit to the left
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+6], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+5], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+4], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+3], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+2], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx+1], al
PSLLW xmm0, 1
PMOVMSKB eax, xmm0
MOV [ecx], al
```

25 x86 opcodes/instructions as opposed to the stacked `for` loop solution with 64 iterations.

Comment: The question is tagged embedded an c, there is quite a good chance that he is not working on x86 at all. (OTOH he might be.)