# different representation of array element

Tags: c, arrays

consider following C code

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
printf("%d",2[a]);
```

this prints "3".How is it possible? I know in a[2] a is the base address of array.But in 2[a]
what is 2? and how it accessses array a?I am totally confused with this representation of array.

Comment: Nice catch on the duplicate, @devnull ! I have to admit I did not know the answer.

Comment: @Floris Looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14547307/2235132), I must say that I don't believe you.

Comment: @devnull it's true: I am a self-taught hacker; as such I have occasional areas of real depth, and other complete blind spots. Which is why I hang around on this site a lot... But yeah - that was an answer I still feel pretty good about :-)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to remember here:

- The first is that array access is basically just a fancy way of using pointer arithmetic. For example, if you have the array

  ```
  int a[10];
  ```

  then

  ```
  a[3] = 5;
  ```

  is equal to

  ```
  *(a + 3) = 5;
  ```
- The second thing to remember is that addition (like in `a + 3` above) is [commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative), so `a + 3` is the same as `3 + a`. This leads to e.g.

  ```
  *(3 + a) = 5;
  ```

  which can be interpreted as

  ```
  3[a] = 5;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`int a[]={1,2,3,4};` is an integer array containing 4 elements and  `a`  is the Base Address, Let the Base Address  be denoted by  `X` . Now  `a[1]` means element at address `X` + `sizeOf(int) * 2` = `Y` (suppose) i.e. element at address `Y`,  likewise `2[a]` means element at adsress `sizeOf(int) * 2` * `X`  =  `Y`.

Thus even if you write `a[2]` or `2[a]` eventually complier recognizes it as `Y` and refres to the element at address `Y` which is  `3` in our case.

Hope it addresses the problem right.

Answer (score 0):

```
*(expr1+expr2) is equivalent to expr1[expr2] or expr2[expr1].

*(expr2+expr1) is equivalent to expr2[expr1] or expr1[expr2].
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just another way to write an element of an array.

In `int a[]={1,2,3,4};`, element at index 3 can be referenced by many methods:

1. As an array element: `a[3]`
2. Using pointer: `*(a + 3)` or `*(3 + a)` [Addition is commutative in arithmetics and in C]
3. Now you can write the second way of representation using pointer as `3[a]`, i.e. `a[3]` is equal to `*(a + 3)` is equal to `*(3 + a)` is equal to `3[a]`.