# Multiplication by constant in fewest adds and shifts

Tags: z3, multiplication, smt, sat

It is possible to multiply two numbers by using just [addition, subtraction and shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add). The important part of the procedure is to find the minimal (optimal) sequence of such operations. Using brute force to find the sequence leads to exponential growth of difficulty so various heuristics are used, perhaps the most commonly known is the paper [Multiplication by integer constant](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=10752) by Robert Bernstein.

Example for multiplying by 113, as given in [Multiplication by an Integer Constant](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072430/) by Vincent Lefevre:

```
  3x <-  x << 1 + x
  7x <- 3x << 1 + x
113x <- 7x << 4 + x
```

I stumbled upon a very interesting [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551792) which got me wondering: would it be possible to use Z3 (or similar) to find the minimal sequence of operators to multiply numbers by the given constant? I'm very new to all this SAT and SMT so I'm not sure if it makes sense at all in the context of Boolean satisfiability problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is indeed possible. Note however that the problem is NP-hard.

We did an experiment a while ago with a more general problem (multiple constant multiplication): http://web.ist.utl.pt/nuno.lopes/pubs/mcm-pb10.pdf

Basically the results were pretty disappointing. Specialized algorithms were much faster.

Comment: AFAIK, it is just conjectured to be NP-hard. I have read 2 old articles claiming to prove the NP-completeness of some variant of SCM or MCM, but they were both wrong (one because the reformulation of the problem was plainly incorrect, and IIRC, the other one was wrong for NP-hard and regarded NP as obvious, which isn't if one doesn't artificially bound the shift count).