# Transform / rotate bits in byte array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, transform, bit

I'm looking for a way to quickly rotate the bits in a byte array without massive for loops that gets and sets each bit from old to new position.  In this particular circumstance I need to rotate by 90 degrees clockwise.
So for instance if I have:

```
unsigned char array[8] = {
0b11110000,
0b10000000,
0b10000000,
0b10000000,
0b00000000,
0b00000000,
0b00000000,
0b00000001
};
```

I need to get:

```
unsigned char array[8] = {
0b00001111,
0b00000001,
0b00000001,
0b00000001,
0b00000000,
0b00000000,
0b00000000,
0b10000000
};
```

Looking for the most efficient way possible to do this ... but it may not always be an 8x8 grid of bits.  Will always be power of 2 dimension though (if that helps!)

Comment: You will not be able to transform you char array without a for-loop.

Comment: There is no built-in support in C or most of the underlying hardware to do it in any easy way.

Comment: I ought to point out that I don't mean "no for loops at all"!  Just not the nested for loops required to transform each bit, one by one.

Comment: choose C or C++, i suggest C++ since there is no way to do this in C.

Comment: @Gab: Well of course you can, but that would be unecessarily cumbersome.

Comment: @paulsoulsby If you have an implementation in mind - post it here. It is not clear why nested loops are needed.

Comment: It's for part of a routine to write to an Oled display.  I want to create some custom characters on the fly with a canvas that is (e.g.) 64x16 bits.  But the routine to write to the oled requires 8x8 blocks, with each block rotated 90s degrees (so that it appears correct on the oled).

Comment: Of course you can do it in C, @Abra.  But I'm curious, do you have in mind some easy way to do it in C++ that is not doable in the subset in common with C?

Comment: @JohnBollinger maybe `std::rotate` in `<algorithm.h>`

Comment: @JohnBollinger: with template abuse :-)

Comment: @Abra, `std::rotate` does not do the job the OP wants to do.

Comment: oh ok i misunderstood the question.sorry. But there is still `for_each` iterator that spares much writing. @JohnBollinger

Comment: @Jarod42, it seems almost anything can be accomplished via template abuse :-).  Still, I'm not seeing that it affords any *easy* way to accomplish the OP's objective.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I think what SaniSinghHuttunen does manually can be done with template not so hardly.

Comment: @Jarod42, I don't see that Sani's solution would benefit from a template at all.  And I also do not see that it is a complete solution (nor could it be made one by templating, I think), since the OP says the problem size is not fixed at 8 x 8.

Comment: If speed is more important than memory, create an array of 8 bytes that holds the new bit position for every possible single bit and OR them together with a single loop.

Comment: [Rotate a bitmap represented by an array of bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35544172/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Cumbersome but without for-loops:

```
rotatedArray[0] = (array[7] & 128) || (array[6] & 128) >> 1 || (array[5] & 128) >> 2 || (array[4] & 128) >> 3 || (array[3] & 128) >> 4 || (array[2] & 128) >> 5 || (array[1] & 128) >> 6 || (array[0] & 128) >> 7;

rotatedArray[1] = (array[7] & 64) << 1 || (array[6] & 64) || (array[5] & 64) >> 1 || (array[4] & 64) >> 2 || (array[3] & 64) >> 3 || (array[2] & 64) >> 4 || (array[1] & 64) >> 5 || (array[0] & 64) >> 6;

rotatedArray[2] = (array[7] & 32) << 2 || (array[6] & 32) << 1|| (array[5] & 32) || (array[4] & 32) >> 1 || (array[3] & 32) >> 2 || (array[2] & 32) >> 3 || (array[1] & 32) >> 4 || (array[0] & 32) >> 5;

...

rotatedArray[7] = (array[7] & 1) << 7 || (array[6] & 1) << 6 || (array[5] & 1) << 5 || (array[4] & 1) << 4 || (array[3] & 1) << 3 || (array[2] & 1) << 2 || (array[1] & 1) << 1 || (array[0] & 1);
```

**Edit**

If the canvas is limited to 32x8 (8 32-bit integers) and the result should be 4 8x8 blocks, then without for-loops:

```
rotatedArray[0][0] = (array[7] & 0x80000000) >> 24 || (array[6] & 0x80000000) >> 25 || (array[5] & 0x80000000) >> 26 || (array[4] & 0x80000000) >> 27 || (array[3] & 0x80000000) >> 28 || (array[2] & 0x80000000) >> 29 || (array[1] & 0x80000000) >> 30 || (array[0] & 0x80000000) >> 31;
rotatedArray[0][1] = (array[7] & 0x40000000) >> 23 || (array[6] & 0x40000000) >> 24 || (array[5] & 0x40000000) >> 25 || (array[4] & 0x40000000) >> 26 || (array[3] & 0x40000000) >> 27 || (array[2] & 0x40000000) >> 28 || (array[1] & 0x40000000) >> 29 || (array[0] & 0x40000000) >> 30;
rotatedArray[0][2] = (array[7] & 0x20000000) >> 22 || (array[6] & 0x2000000) >> 23 || (array[5] & 0x20000000) >> 24 || (array[4] & 0x20000000) >> 25 || (array[3] & 0x20000000) >> 26 || (array[2] & 0x20000000) >> 27 || (array[1] & 0x20000000) >> 28 || (array[0] & 0x20000000) >> 29;
rotatedArray[0][3] = (array[7] & 0x10000000) >> 21 || (array[6] & 0x10000000) >> 22 || (array[5] & 0x10000000) >> 23 || (array[4] & 0x10000000) >> 24 || (array[3] & 0x10000000) >> 25 || (array[2] & 0x10000000) >> 26 || (array[1] & 0x10000000) >> 27 || (array[0] & 0x10000000) >> 28;
rotatedArray[0][4] = (array[7] & 0x8000000) >> 20 || (array[6] & 0x8000000) >> 21 || (array[5] & 0x8000000) >> 22 || (array[4] & 0x8000000) >> 23 || (array[3] & 0x8000000) >> 24 || (array[2] & 0x8000000) >> 25 || (array[1] & 0x8000000) >> 26 || (array[0] & 0x8000000) >> 27;
rotatedArray[0][5] = (array[7] & 0x4000000) >> 19 || (array[6] & 0x4000000) >> 20 || (array[5] & 0x4000000) >> 21 || (array[4] & 0x4000000) >> 22 || (array[3] & 0x4000000) >> 23 || (array[2] & 0x4000000) >> 24 || (array[1] & 0x4000000) >> 25 || (array[0] & 0x4000000) >> 26;
rotatedArray[0][6] = (array[7] & 0x2000000) >> 18 || (array[6] & 0x2000000) >> 19 || (array[5] & 0x2000000) >> 20 || (array[4] & 0x2000000) >> 21 || (array[3] & 0x2000000) >> 22 || (array[2] & 0x2000000) >> 23 || (array[1] & 0x2000000) >> 24 || (array[0] & 0x2000000) >> 25;
rotatedArray[0][7] = (array[7] & 0x1000000) >> 17 || (array[6] & 0x1000000) >> 18 || (array[5] & 0x1000000) >> 19 || (array[4] & 0x1000000) >> 20 || (array[3] & 0x1000000) >> 21 || (array[2] & 0x1000000) >> 22 || (array[1] & 0x1000000) >> 23 || (array[0] & 0x1000000) >> 24;

rotatedArray[1][0] = (array[7] & 0x800000) >> 16 || (array[6] & 0x800000) >> 17 || (array[5] & 0x800000) >> 18 || (array[4] & 0x800000) >> 19 || (array[3] & 0x800000) >> 20 || (array[2] & 0x800000) >> 21 || (array[1] & 0x800000) >> 22 || (array[0] & 0x800000) >> 23;
rotatedArray[1][1] = (array[7] & 0x400000) >> 15 || (array[6] & 0x400000) >> 16 || (array[5] & 0x400000) >> 17 || (array[4] & 0x400000) >> 18 || (array[3] & 0x400000) >> 19 || (array[2] & 0x400000) >> 20 || (array[1] & 0x400000) >> 21 || (array[0] & 0x400000) >> 22;
rotatedArray[1][2] = (array[7] & 0x200000) >> 14 || (array[6] & 0x200000) >> 15 || (array[5] & 0x200000) >> 16 || (array[4] & 0x200000) >> 17 || (array[3] & 0x200000) >> 18 || (array[2] & 0x200000) >> 19 || (array[1] & 0x200000) >> 20 || (array[0] & 0x200000) >> 21;
rotatedArray[1][3] = (array[7] & 0x100000) >> 13 || (array[6] & 0x100000) >> 14 || (array[5] & 0x100000) >> 15 || (array[4] & 0x100000) >> 16 || (array[3] & 0x100000) >> 17 || (array[2] & 0x100000) >> 18 || (array[1] & 0x100000) >> 19 || (array[0] & 0x100000) >> 20;
rotatedArray[1][4] = (array[7] & 0x80000) >> 12 || (array[6] & 0x80000) >> 13 || (array[5] & 0x80000) >> 14 || (array[4] & 0x80000) >> 15 || (array[3] & 0x80000) >> 16 || (array[2] & 0x80000) >> 17 || (array[1] & 0x80000) >> 18 || (array[0] & 0x80000) >> 19;
rotatedArray[1][5] = (array[7] & 0x40000) >> 11 || (array[6] & 0x40000) >> 12 || (array[5] & 0x40000) >> 13 || (array[4] & 0x40000) >> 14 || (array[3] & 0x40000) >> 15 || (array[2] & 0x40000) >> 16 || (array[1] & 0x40000) >> 17 || (array[0] & 0x40000) >> 18;
rotatedArray[1][6] = (array[7] & 0x20000) >> 10 || (array[6] & 0x20000) >> 11 || (array[5] & 0x20000) >> 12 || (array[4] & 0x20000) >> 13 || (array[3] & 0x20000) >> 14 || (array[2] & 0x20000) >> 15 || (array[1] & 0x20000) >> 16 || (array[0] & 0x20000) >> 17;
rotatedArray[1][7] = (array[7] & 0x10000) >> 9 || (array[6] & 0x10000) >> 10 || (array[5] & 0x10000) >> 11 || (array[4] & 0x10000) >> 12 || (array[3] & 0x10000) >> 13 || (array[2] & 0x10000) >> 14 || (array[1] & 0x10000) >> 15 || (array[0] & 0x10000) >> 16;

rotatedArray[2][0] = (array[7] & 0x8000) >> 8 || (array[6] & 0x8000) >> 9 || (array[5] & 0x8000) >> 10 || (array[4] & 0x8000) >> 11 || (array[3] & 0x8000) >> 12 || (array[2] & 0x8000) >> 13 || (array[1] & 0x8000) >> 14 || (array[0] & 0x8000) >> 15;
rotatedArray[2][1] = (array[7] & 0x4000) >> 7 || (array[6] & 0x4000) >> 8 || (array[5] & 0x4000) >> 9 || (array[4] & 0x4000) >> 10 || (array[3] & 0x4000) >> 11 || (array[2] & 0x4000) >> 12 || (array[1] & 0x4000) >> 13 || (array[0] & 0x4000) >> 14;
rotatedArray[2][2] = (array[7] & 0x2000) >> 6 || (array[6] & 0x2000) >> 7 || (array[5] & 0x2000) >> 8 || (array[4] & 0x2000) >> 9 || (array[3] & 0x2000) >> 10 || (array[2] & 0x2000) >> 11 || (array[1] & 0x2000) >> 12 || (array[0] & 0x2000) >> 13;
rotatedArray[2][3] = (array[7] & 0x1000) >> 5 || (array[6] & 0x1000) >> 6 || (array[5] & 0x1000) >> 7 || (array[4] & 0x1000) >> 8 || (array[3] & 0x1000) >> 9 || (array[2] & 0x1000) >> 10 || (array[1] & 0x1000) >> 11 || (array[0] & 0x1000) >> 12;
rotatedArray[2][4] = (array[7] & 0x800) >> 4 || (array[6] & 0x800) >> 5 || (array[5] & 0x800) >> 6 || (array[4] & 0x800) >> 7 || (array[3] & 0x800) >> 8 || (array[2] & 0x800) >> 9 || (array[1] & 0x800) >> 10 || (array[0] & 0x800) >> 11;
rotatedArray[2][5] = (array[7] & 0x400) >> 3 || (array[6] & 0x400) >> 4 || (array[5] & 0x400) >> 5 || (array[4] & 0x400) >> 6 || (array[3] & 0x400) >> 7 || (array[2] & 0x400) >> 8 || (array[1] & 0x400) >> 9 || (array[0] & 0x400) >> 10;
rotatedArray[2][6] = (array[7] & 0x200) >> 2 || (array[6] & 0x200) >> 3 || (array[5] & 0x200) >> 4 || (array[4] & 0x200) >> 5 || (array[3] & 0x200) >> 6 || (array[2] & 0x200) >> 7 || (array[1] & 0x200) >> 8 || (array[0] & 0x200) >> 9;
rotatedArray[2][7] = (array[7] & 0x100) >> 1 || (array[6] & 0x100) >> 2 || (array[5] & 0x100) >> 3 || (array[4] & 0x100) >> 4 || (array[3] & 0x100) >> 5 || (array[2] & 0x100) >> 6 || (array[1] & 0x100) >> 7 || (array[0] & 0x100) >> 8;

rotatedArray[3][0] = (array[7] & 0x80) || (array[6] & 0x80) >> 1 || (array[5] & 0x80) >> 2 || (array[4] & 0x80) >> 3 || (array[3] & 0x80) >> 4 || (array[2] & 0x80) >> 5 || (array[1] & 0x80) >> 6 || (array[0] & 0x80) >> 7;
rotatedArray[3][1] = (array[7] & 0x40) << 1 || (array[6] & 0x40) || (array[5] & 0x40) >> 1 || (array[4] & 0x40) >> 2 || (array[3] & 0x40) >> 3 || (array[2] & 0x40) >> 4 || (array[1] & 0x40) >> 5 || (array[0] & 0x40) >> 6;
rotatedArray[3][2] = (array[7] & 0x20) << 2 || (array[6] & 0x20) << 1 || (array[5] & 0x20) || (array[4] & 0x20) >> 1 || (array[3] & 0x20) >> 2 || (array[2] & 0x20) >> 3 || (array[1] & 0x20) >> 4 || (array[0] & 0x20) >> 5;
rotatedArray[3][3] = (array[7] & 0x10) << 3 || (array[6] & 0x10) << 2 || (array[5] & 0x10) << 1 || (array[4] & 0x10) || (array[3] & 0x10) >> 1 || (array[2] & 0x10) >> 2 || (array[1] & 0x10) >> 3 || (array[0] & 0x10) >> 4;
rotatedArray[3][4] = (array[7] & 0x8) << 4 || (array[6] & 0x8) << 3 || (array[5] & 0x8) << 2 || (array[4] & 0x8) << 1 || (array[3] & 0x8) || (array[2] & 0x8) >> 1 || (array[1] & 0x8) >> 2 || (array[0] & 0x8) >> 3;
rotatedArray[3][5] = (array[7] & 0x4) << 5 || (array[6] & 0x4) << 4 || (array[5] & 0x4) << 3 || (array[4] & 0x4) << 2 || (array[3] & 0x4) << 1 || (array[2] & 0x4) || (array[1] & 0x4) >> 1 || (array[0] & 0x4) >> 2;
rotatedArray[3][6] = (array[7] & 0x2) << 6 || (array[6] & 0x2) << 5 || (array[5] & 0x2) << 4 || (array[4] & 0x2) << 3 || (array[3] & 0x2) << 2 || (array[2] & 0x2) << 1 || (array[1] & 0x2) || (array[0] & 0x2) >> 1;
rotatedArray[3][7] = (array[7] & 0x1) << 7 || (array[6] & 0x1) << 6 || (array[5] & 0x1) << 5 || (array[4] & 0x1) << 4 || (array[3] & 0x1) << 3 || (array[2] & 0x1) << 2 || (array[1] & 0x1) << 1 || (array[0] & 0x1);
```

**Disclaimer**: *Might be some mistakes but you get the idea.*

Comment: Yes for the OP's example, but he says the dimensions may not always be 8.

Comment: Yes , this is essentially manually unrolling the loops.  It may be an acceptable route to take if no better solution can be found.  I could always break the bigger canvas down in to 8x8 blocks first.

Comment: @paulsoulsby, I'm not seeing how breaking a larger canvas into 8x8 blocks would assist you with performing the computation you describe -- unless you meant a collection of blockwise rotations in the first place?

Comment: Well, actually, I guess it could help, but you would still need to perform a bunch of subsequent *byte*wise rearrangements after the blockwise ones.  That might still yield a net win, but you'll have some loop nests.

Comment: If there are few possible dimensions (like only 8x8, 64x16, 32x32 and 128x64) you could write different functions for each dimension configuration and do without any for-loops. However if the dimensions can be arbitrary (canvas from 8x8 to AxB and any permutation in between) then you'll one way or another end up with nested for-loops. Best bet would be, as you say, to split the canvas into 8x8 blocks with nested for-loops.

Comment: Come to think of it. Only a single for-loop is necessary if you unroll the inner loop and use division and modulus on the counter for indexing. So you COULD do without nesting but hardly worth the effort.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the situation I’m actually requiring will store 8 32-bit ints, ie a 32x8 canvas with each 8x8 block rotated by 90 degrees. I think I may have confused the situation with that part! 8x8 block rotates are fine and I’ll then shift them into correct position in the 32bit int.